What should one do with pocket tens from the small blind following a raise from under the gun and a re-raise from the hijack?
In Maria Konnikova's 2020 book The Biggest Bluff, she writes:

As I ride the subway back to Brooklyn, I realize Erik hasn't given me much in the way of concrete advice.
[...]
And yes, it is frustrating. I do want answers. I do want a guide for what to do with my pocket tens from the small blind following a raise from under the gun and a re-raise from the hijack. Enough philosophy, I want to yell. Give me certainty!

So let's give her some concrete advice and answer this particular question for her. What should one do in that specific situation?

Asking for certainty in a game of decision making with an incomplete dataset is not something people can give you. People aren't machines, they don't play perfect poker and every situation is going to be unique. You, yourself haven't even given enough information for anything other than a vague, general advice/considerations.

It depends and is extremely situational. Given you haven't given any specific details other than a vague situation I'll just give you some general guidelines and thoughts. As a general suggestion the more information you can give the easier and better advice you can get from poker questions.
Game
What are you playing needs to be considered. Is it a tournament or a cash game? Tournaments your decision could be decided by the tournament stage, i.e. if you're on the bubble or at a pay jump you might not want to take the risk. Likewise in a cash game if you have an easy post flop decision where you're going to hit a set or just fold, etc. Cash plays different than tournaments and depending on the stage of the tournament and what the money means to you matters.
Stacks
Firstly you haven't given details on stack sizes, this is core information that would very much dictate what we do.
Short stack sizes (less than 20BBs) involved, from either UTG, HJ or yourself, you should probably give serious consideration to shoving. TT is a top 10 starting hands. It's like JJ, very strong but potentially hard to play and navigate post-flop.
Medium to deep stacks (Greater than 30 BBs) involved the decision becomes more nuanced and massively depends on your ability to play and the opponent. It is a lot more appropriate to call and navigate a flop here, of course it depends on the opponent and indeed yourself and your discipline.
Opponent
Always consider who you're playing against. No one plays GTO, we all make mistakes, we all have our own comfort level and we all have our own little quirks. Consider these when you're making a decision.
As an example is the player extremely tight OMC. Let's say you've been at this table for 3/4 hours or have a history with the player and you know their range has TTs in bad shape, just fold.
Likewise if you know the player has a wide range in the HJ and UTG then consider 4-betting potentially. Especially if you have a tight reputation. General rule if your range plays better than your opponent it opens up your options. Hands always play better heads-up rather than multi-way, especially if we're going to shove.
Your image
Like I mentioned above about OMC who is tight, and indeed your own image, you need to consider how you're actions are likely going to be perceived. If you've been playing any two all day and playing aggressively you're 4 bet won't get much credit so you'll likely be called lighter.
This is a double edged sword of course as if you're playing like that you're at the top of your range, but you're introducing more variance. Again as mentioned already you need to understand the stage of the tournament, the value of money, etc.
Same is visa versa true in the inverse, i.e. if you've only played a tight range of AQ+ TT+ then a 4 bet will be more likely to succeed as players would be more worried that you could have them crushed.
Some General Suggestions
Again we need more information but take these as some general pieces of advice.

Against a Tight UTC or HJ - Just fold, there are better spots, and it's always harder to play OOP.
Against agro players, shorter stacks - Consider a 4 bet shove
Same as situation as 2 - Consider a call and see how the flop is, low flops good, sets amazing (but maybe hard to be paid off on), high flops bad which makes an easy fold for you.
Against agro players, deep stacks - All options available, call and see a flop. 4 bet and fold to a 5 bet, etc.

All of these depend on your own ability to play, navigate post-flop, how the money matters to you, who you're playing, how they view you, etc.
TL;DR - Like everything in Poker it depends. It's important that you factor as much information into your decision as possible. Think the situation through rather than have auto-pilot, cookie cutter approaches.
